# windows 7 x64 ultimate freezes randomly

Tags: windows

I am trying to figure this out like 2 months. the problem is windows freezes between 15 min - 4 hours randomly. After format It seems stop (can't know because of random) but after install things (looks a like after install visual studio or skype) problem came back, It seems software problem pc service couldn't find problem on psu/ram/vga.he couldn't test mainboard and cpu.

my configuration is,

```
i5 750
MSI P55M-GD41
Nvidia 8800 GS
2x4 GB Corsair XMS3
Creative SB Audigy
```

after Its freeze, If I listen music/movie sound stop for 2 sec then continue without problem. but screen is frozen.

When I check Event Log, I see too many "Service Control Manager 7036" I don't know if this is normal. Also tried disable all startup services except microsofts.

Event Log

```
Information 27.01.2013 20:58:44 Kernel-Processor-Power  26  (4)
Information 27.01.2013 20:58:44 Kernel-Processor-Power  26  (4)
Information 27.01.2013 20:58:44 Kernel-Processor-Power  26  (4)
Information 27.01.2013 20:58:44 Kernel-Processor-Power  26  (4)
Critical    27.01.2013 20:58:42 Kernel-Power    41  (63)
Information 27.01.2013 20:59:00 EventLog    6013    None
Information 27.01.2013 20:59:00 EventLog    6005    None
Information 27.01.2013 20:59:00 EventLog    6009    None
Error       27.01.2013 20:59:00 EventLog    6008    None
Information 27.01.2013 20:58:36 FilterManager   6   None
Information 27.01.2013 20:58:35 Kernel-General  12  None
Information 27.01.2013 20:35:13 Service Control Manager 7036    None
Information 27.01.2013 20:27:52 Service Control Manager 7036    None
Information 27.01.2013 20:26:25 Service Control Manager 7036    None
Information 27.01.2013 20:25:00 Service Control Manager 7036    None
Information 27.01.2013 20:24:23 Service Control Manager 7036    None
Information 27.01.2013 20:24:12 Service Control Manager 7036    None
```

The Stop error BugcheckCode value is listed as zero.
maybe I cause the Kernel-Power by shuting down the pc.

I tried to stress pc, my cpu temperature hit up to 100 C° I used some time like that, also played games still no problem, but while surf on internet or watch a movie or just check some folders can make pc freeze. what I achieved is this is nothing to do with stressing pc.

Comment: Check this KB article and check the steps from scenario 3: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Comment: I checked the document, "The Stop error BugcheckCode value is listed as zero." and "You might also see this scenario if the computer is “hard-locked” and therefore unresponsive to any input, and the computer has to be powered off." these are fits for me. but I couldn't do the caps-lock test because I don't have leds on my keyboard. wireless keyboard need to save battery I think.

Comment: check all 5 steps from scenario 3.

Comment: I checked all and all clear. still problem occurs.

Comment: If it also happens after a complete reinstall my guess would be a hardware failure. Seems it has nothing to do with overheating or generally insufficient power supply. Maybe a broken mainboard, graphics card or power supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I figure it out, It was overheating problem. I changed the thermal paste on cpu, problem got away in some days.